# Select columns without using subquery in mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

I want to select some records from table "A" but records that are not in table "B".

Example...
Tables are...

```
A{A_ID, A_Date, A_Price};

B{B_ID, A_ID};
```

I want to select records from table "A" with primary key A_ID but only those records that are not table "B" on joining both table on primary key A_ID.
I can do this with query...

```
select * from A where A_ID not in (select A_ID from B)
```

but my problem is subquery. Because it takes too much time run, if data quantity big.

**SO I WANT TO RUN IT WITHOUT SUBQUERY.**

please help!!!

Comment: please post example

Answer (score 1):

Try these queries:

```
select * from TableA A
where not exists(select 1 from TableB where A_ID = A.A_ID)
```

or

```
select A.* from TableA A left join TableB B
on A.A_ID = B.A_ID
where B.B_ID is null
```

Comment: Both queries takes too much time, if data quantity is big. First query contains subquery, solution must be without subquery, because it takes more time to run

Comment: Do you have indexes on these tables? If not, this is the way to go.

Comment: Yes, but not on A_ID and B_ID

Comment: You should create indexes on these columns as well. Then my queries should work well (also `not exists` is preferred over `not in`).

Comment: @narhari You should accept the answer if it helped and optinally upvote, if you feel like :)